# Images gallery in WPF with filters

Tags: wpf, image-gallery, pivotviewer

Looking to present a batch of images (about 10,000) with multiple characteristics to filters. I wish some of the closest thing PivotViewer Silverlight.
I find no free or paid component that this kind of thing in WPF.
Unable to transform the Silverlight component WPF and I do not think to insert silverlight in a WPF application is a good thing.
Would you have a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try some of these:

- http://jmcspot.com/JMC_Photo_Gallery/Default
- https://wpfimagegallery.codeplex.com/

If you use a VirtualizingStackPanel as the container, you can theoretically display immense amounts of data without running out of memory.

Comment: Thanks, I your first link. Actually I develop a custom solution to do this with VirtualizingWrapPanel but it’s strange that Microsoft or others don’t develop a PivotViewer-Like in WPF